# Name Error Global name 'class name' is not defined for class

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I execute the below code in visual studio code, I get the following error:

"NameError: global name 'TestClass' is not defined"

I have checked previous posts + the python docs and it seems like my code SHOULD work.

```
import struct

def test():
    print "test"
    instance = TestClass("55555")


test()

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, test):
        self.Text = test

    def ConvertLongToByteArr(self,longInput):
        returnBytes = bytearray(struct.pack(longInput))
        return returnBytes

    def Decrypt(self,input):
        print input
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a matter of ordering. You have to define the TestClass before you use it:

```
import struct

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, test):
        self.Text = test

    def ConvertLongToByteArr(self,longInput):
        returnBytes = bytearray(struct.pack(longInput))
        return returnBytes

    def Decrypt(self,input):
        print(input)

def test():
    print("test")
    instance = TestClass("55555")

test() # test
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling an instance of the object TestClass before you are declaring the class. try:
import struct

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, test):
        self.Text = test

    def ConvertLongToByteArr(self,longInput):
        returnBytes = bytearray(struct.pack(longInput))
        return returnBytes

    def Decrypt(self,input):
        print input 


def test():
    print "test"
    instance = TestClass("55555")


test()
```